# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined in phaser while using game.add.text()

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

This is my code which i tried.

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>Cat Catcher 2000</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var game = new Phaser.Game(800,600, Phaser.CANVAS,'cat-catcher', {preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
            var cat,catcher,cursors,txtScore,score;
            function preload(){
                game.load.image('cat','img/cat.png');
                game.load.image('catcher','img/catcher.png');
                game.load.image('bg','img/bg.png');
            }
            function create(){
                // background setup
                game.add.sprite(0,0,"bg");
                // catcher setup
                catcher = game.add.sprite(400,300,'catcher');
                catcher.anchor.setTo(0.5,0);
                game.physics.enable(catcher,Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
                // cat setup
                cat = game.add.sprite(Math.random() * game.width , Math.random() * game.height, 'cat');
                game.physics.enable(cat,Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
                // Score setup
                score = 0;
                var style = {font: "Arial", fill: "#fff"};
                txtScore = game.add.text(10,10,score.toString(),style);

            }
            function update(){

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

While running the above code i got the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined** inside the create function and particularly in the line

```
txtScore = game.add.text(10,10,score.toString(),style);
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
http://phaser.io â™¥â™¥â™¥
phaser.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at c.Text.setStyle (phaser.min.js:3)
    at new c.Text (phaser.min.js:3)
    at c.GameObjectFactory.text (phaser.min.js:3)
    at Object.create (index.html:26)
    at c.StateManager.loadComplete (phaser.min.js:3)
    at c.Loader.finishedLoading (phaser.min.js:3)
    at c.Loader.processLoadQueue (phaser.min.js:3)
    at c.Loader.asyncComplete (phaser.min.js:3)
    at c.Loader.fileComplete (phaser.min.js:3)
    at HTMLImageElement.a.data.onload (phaser.min.js:3)
c.Text.setStyle @ phaser.min.js:3
c.Text @ phaser.min.js:3
text @ phaser.min.js:3
create @ index.html:26
loadComplete @ phaser.min.js:3
finishedLoading @ phaser.min.js:3
processLoadQueue @ phaser.min.js:3
asyncComplete @ phaser.min.js:3
fileComplete @ phaser.min.js:3
a.data.onload @ phaser.min.js:3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `toLowerCase` is not called in your question so I assume it's called by functions in `game`. So the code above is insufficient to reproduce the problem. Can you either provide more details or console output the suspicious lines to see which variable is actually called when having `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Comment: i add the console output to the question bro

Comment: Check this one `create @ index.html:26`. This is only one in your console output that's not in `phaser.min.js`. So do have a look at that line and see what's been happening.

Comment: What version of Phaser are you using? I can't replicate this on 2.6.2.

Comment: I am using "phaser CE 2.7.8" and also I found that error. actually, phaser needs to align,boundsAlignV and boundsAlignH style attribute to align the text. in the code `var style = {}` the error is gone after I added the necessary style attribute. thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using "phaser CE 2.7.8" and I found the solution for that error. actually, phaser needs to align,boundsAlignV and boundsAlignH style attribute to align the text. in the code var style = {} the error is gone after I added the necessary style attribute.

**CORRECT CODE**

```
`function create(){
                // background setup
                game.add.sprite(0,0,"bg");
                // catcher setup
                catcher = game.add.sprite(400,300,'catcher');
                catcher.anchor.setTo(0.5,0);
                game.physics.enable(catcher,Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
                // cat setup
                cat = game.add.sprite(Math.random() * game.width , Math.random() * game.height, 'cat');
                game.physics.enable(cat,Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
                // Score setup
                score = 0;
                var style = {font: "20px Arial", fill: "#fff",align:"left",boundsAlignH: "top",boundsAlignV:"top"};**// NOTE THIS LINE**
                txtScore = game.add.text(10,10,score.toString(),style);

            }`
```

**Note the var style={} line in the above code i added the neccessary properties.**
thanks, everyone!